# How to resolve LWC component page load error?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using the Lighting record form in the LWC component and displaying some fields. But we don't need those fields on the Details tab. If I remove those fields from the Page layout, I get the below error.

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Is both LWC and detail page used in same record page? Kindly share code on how fields are displayed in LWC.

Comment: Yes @JPM, both LWC and detail page used in same record page.

Comment: Kindly edit your question to share LWC's js code